# event handler in ASP

Tags: javascript, redirect, asp-classic, event-handling

i have a page where an admin can see all the user information and edit it with update button(form post). but i need a button on the top says log in as user which logout the admin and login as that user and land on user home page. I was wondering that is there any way we can handle that button event? I am new to this and after searching for few hours on web i found that its easy to handle event in ASP.net but in classic asp its hard.

i found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lisawoll/archive/2004/07/22/191692.aspx

and tried but didnt work.

please help me.

Comment: You should handle those button event on javascript - why do you want to handle it on the server ? all asp.net does is sends a useless post requests to the server in every <asp:button click - this is a bad practice and horrible performance - you should avoid this in any cost

Comment: The requirement from my client is like that. Admin can see user information but there are some times whre user can not post a job(its a job website) so my client wants that in admin section where we see user information,he needs a button there says "Log in as user" which logs out him as admin and open home page and loggedin as user so perform those tasks.  The link which i posted is for radio button and its on  the same page. What i want is on click of that button user should be redirected to user home page with loogedin as user.

Comment: What i tried to do is wrote a code in JAVA SCRIPT where i am changing the session information from Admin to user with the info i ahve from the user page and redirecting the page to user home page. I thought redirected page takes user info from the session info which i changed and dont have to send any data to server.

I might be wrong.but let me know if you have a better way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: So what the server got to do with anything here ? your link is referring to also events handles in client side(this like uses vbscript which is outdated and does not support in any browser) you should use javascript - now - what are you trying to do again - I did not understand - try to be more clear

Comment: So what i am trying to do is. I log in as Admin and i search for a user. I click the user from the list view and it will open a page which dispaly user profile info(userid,passmcomp name etc). Now in past we had some problem where user were unable to post job from their account so we send them an email and they give us their userid and pass and we log in as them and post those job. What we want now is instead of asking them user/pass we want a button on that user profile page. By clicking on that button we should be land on User Home page(logged in as that user) and log out as admin.

Comment: Well - there are several ways to do that. one of them is to just send a request to the server to change the login to the user session with the user_id as parameter - in this page check if the request is under admin session and if so just change the session and refresh the page - you know how to do it ?

Comment: in a nutshell admin/user_prof.asp have user profile. Theree will be a button which says log in as user.If i click on that i will be logeedout and land on user_home.asp page which will be a user homepage and i will be log in as user. Sorry if its still confusing. i have been working on this project since last 10 hours so you can understand my mind situation. i hope this explain you better what i am doing. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Client side - the button

```
<form method="post" action="MyLoginAsUserEventHandlerPage.asp">
...
   <input type="submit" name="btnLoginAsUser" value="Login as User" />
</form>
```

Server side:

```
<%
...
If Trim(Request.Form("btnLoginAsUser")) & "" <> "" Then
'the button was clicked - do work
End If
...
%>
...
```